# How to make query of AND & OR operation from list of elements we we to search in ndb datastore using python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a list of keys of different model entities. 
Example:-

```
list_1 = ['<entity key of model 1>', '<entity key of model 2>', '<entity key of model 3>']
```

i want to query that dynamically forms AND operation from the list.

Example:-

```
query = <SOME MODEL>.query(ndb.AND(<SOME MODEL>.entity == list_1[0], <SOME MODEL>.entity == list_1[1], <SOME MODEL>.entity == list_1[2]))
```

Any help to do such kind of query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Model.entity in your example isn't a repeated property, then this query makes no sense, but something like this will do what you want:

```
q = Model.query()
for item in list_1:
  q = q.filter(Model.entity == item)
```

If you want it in one line, then something like this:

```
q = Model.query(ndb.AND(*(Model.entity == item for item in list_1)))
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and, as you hint, `entity = nbd.KeyProperty(repeated=True)` had *better* be part of the `SOME MODEL` the OP is querying... only way the multiple, `AND`ed equality constraints can possibly make sense!-)

Comment: Any reference to study about * in `ndb.AND(*(Model.entity == item for item in list_1))`? I am a newbie. Please help!